# Json.loads() and json.load() not parsing my file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to decode my json file to delete an object, I always get the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have searched in numerous sites, anyone have an answer?

Python File:

```
db = open(dbn + '.json', 'r') # dbn is defined earlier in the program
name = input('Profile to delete:    ')
dbl = json.load(db) # <- json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
i = 0
while i != len(dbl):
    if dbl[i]['First Name'] == name:
        dbl.pop(i)
db.close()
db = open(dbn + '.json', 'w')
obj = json.dumps(dbl, indent=4)
db.write(obj + ',' + '\n' + ']')
db.close()
```

There are no errors in the JSON file. Basic Structure:

```
[
    { 'x':'y'
    },
    { 'y':'x'
    }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON file. JSON strings must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON you provided has invalid structure.
Python JSON library expects double quotes instead of single quotes, so your JSON file should look like this:

```
[
    { "x":"y"
    },
    { "y":"x"
    }
]
```